# Inserting jquery into Typo3 backend modul

Tags: jquery, typo3, backend

In my backend module I want to use some jQuery functions. The problem is that I get the error :

> .toggleClass is not a function

When i had a look into source code I saw that jQuery, Prototype & Scriptaculous is inserted. I think here should be the problem.

So I tried to put this into my fluid template:

```
<f:be.container loadJQuery="TRUE" loadPrototype="FALSE" loadScriptaculous="FALSE">
```

But it does not help. Is anybody here who has an idea how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you wanted to just use `$.toggleClass`?

You could try to use jQuery.toggleClass instead, this should work in any case.

Comment: A way to handle this too is to use `TYPO3.jQuery.toggleClass`, this should always be available in the backend, as opposed to `$` which might be overwritten, depending on the TYPO3 version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC TYPO3 loads jQuery in no-conflict mode, meaning you have to access it via `jQuery` and `$` will be reserved for Prototype/Scriptaculous.